# Dynamic (variable) database table name versus variable stored in column

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-optimization, scaling, dynamic-tables

Creating an employee management system.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_employees` (
  `employee_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `end_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There are 10 companies for which an employee can work.  There are millions of employees.  Based on coding standards, security and speed, which is better.

1. a separate table for each company which is then referenced dynamically.  Example.  tbl_companya_employees, tbl_companyb_employees, tbl_companyc_employees  **OR**
2. add a company_name column to the tbl_employees table

And why?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new table called company.

```
company 
    company_id int primary_key autoincrement whatever,
    name varchar,
    ... other details ...
```

and then add a company_id column to the employee table.

Better, if you want to retain more than the employee's CURRENT company, create a employee_company_history table:

```
employee_company_history
    employee_id
    company_id 
    start_date
    end_date
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to have a company column in the employee table, this will allow you to write general purpose joins that work with any company. If you have a separate tables, you'll have to write code that generates a dynamic query for the appropriate company.